# How To Use CURL with PHP via the Command Prompt

Tags: php, linux, shell, curl

to start things off, I am currently familiar with using CURL libraries to pass data on php pages, however, I am practicing further options via CURL and I came across something that I don't really know the answer to/architecture on.

I already created a php page that takes passed variables via CURL, utilizes those variables, processes a query based off of the variables and other logic, and it prints out the results to a web page with the results. Works just fine.

My issue is that I want to do this via the command prompt and no UI.

How do I actually initiate the curl command on the command prompt to send (GET/POST) the variables to the php page and then have the results once processed from the page return back on the command prompt? Skipping all UI stuff.

I need to re-do some of the architecture and I'm a little confused on how that would work.

I tried something like this, but no good.

```
curl --request POST 'http://www.somedomain.com/login/' \
--data 'username=myusername&password=mypassword'
```

I am also just echoing out my results right now for testing purposes on the PHP page in hopes that the command prompt would pick it up. Is that right to say?

Any help would be appreciated. Eager to learn

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why aren't you using PHP curl on the command line? 2. Any command you can execute in a Linux shell can be executed from PHP via exec() and output captured, too.

Comment: @marekful I am just doing curl "web address here with parameters". I only know how to pass those parameters via CURL from one php page to another, but when I go to use the shell something is off. There's a specific way to do PHP curl on the command line over regular CURL? or are you saying that I can just execute CURL in the shell to my php file and it can execute it that way? Sorry just trying to follow as running it through the shell with output is new to me.

Comment: Please edit you question. Cut about 90% of description and keep only what is directly relevant to your problem. Include code that you try and have problems with. Describe the expected versus actual behaviour.